# Pull Request outdated label

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a PR where I left several comments in my review on GitHub

A colleague has updated the code to apply my suggested changes, and now all my review comments appear with the outdated label.

However I still see the code in the state it was when I commented it.

What I want is an easy way to see the new code he has written, not the old. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I think GitHub needs to improve it by including the existing commits as is!

Answer (score -4):

Open the PR and Click on the files changed tab. All the latest changes that have been pushed to the branch requesting the PR will be available.

[image: Check this image for visual reference]

Comment: This really isn't an answer. I have a PR with 89 files, scrolling through all the code to that specific commented line isn't an easy way of seeing the new code updates like the question asked.